# HT Access issue

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem with our site after reinstalling the SSL certificate, where the www version of the site (www.mountainx.com) pulls up a completely different site. if you enter the non-www version (mountainx.com), it goes to the correct website. Some of the rules in my .HTAccess file are here - Any help would be appreciated or at least I would like to get a discussion going -

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Also I have a certain number of proxy redirects that are not working either after the SSL change and I had to redirect them to the original hosts. To clarify, we use a third party to host our calendar but want to obscure the URL so it looks like we are still hosting the files. When the SSL certificate was installed, it suddenly started throwing up a 503 error so we agreed to change to the original URL hosted remotely. Also any good tutorials on .htaccess file out there? They seem to be pretty few and far between.

Comment: SO is for questions about programming. Server issues are for serverfault.com

Comment: Ah OK, I have seen a few issues related to .htacess files on Stack Overflow though...

Comment: They just weren't caught.

Comment: @MountainX Whilst `.htaccess` issues relating to application development are arguably on topic here, what you appear to be experiencing is a server configuration issue - this does not appear to have anything to do with `.htaccess`?